# How to uniquely identify tracks in device if they are having same name?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing a music player app.

In developer docs of [`MediaStore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html), no constant is present to uniquely identify the track on the bases of any ID.

Scenario:

I'm also maintaining a Current Playlist, in which user can add individual songs in queue. This list is maintained in DB for displaying same playlist when user runs app next time.

User in his device has 2 songs with same name, viz.:
*/Folder1/abc.mp3 (no album/artist mentioned)
/Folder2/abc.mp3 (no album/artist mentioned)*

Now when user clicks on the song abc.mp3, which track will it play.

I want an additional field while running query that can play correct song.

Thank You

Comment: MAybe the info is already INSIDE the mp3 file. Just try to read Artist/Album from the tags inside the MP3 files. If no info, you can try using the file length in bytes as an id.

Comment: What about [`_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID)?

Comment: @Rajesh _ID of BaseColums - are they based on query result or they remain same throughout MediaStore? I mean if I save SongName + _ID in my CurrentPlaylist table in DB and next time fetch on basis of these 2 fields from `MediaStore.Audio.Media`, do they give same result?